# A shell script acts in a strange way, but why?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, shell, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to run a command on a Fargate ECS task (aws) and to capture its exit code.

There's a known bug in aws cli ecs execute-command sub-command which prevents me from getting the exit status from the commands itself and instead returns the exit status of the underlying layer of aws cli - session manager plugin, more info on that you can read [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/2846).

In order to get the exit status after all, I'm testing it in a few ways, using the "ls -l" instead of the original command I need to use.

This is the command I'm running (it's running on a self hosted Github runner running Ubuntu 20.04):

```
unbuffer aws ecs execute-command \
  --region eu-west-1 \
  --cluster qa-devops-1-productname \
  --task b75a377a63f44938ae7bacc50c852723 \
  --container ops-machine \
  --command 'sh -c "ls -l /productname ; echo $?"' \
  --interactive > some.log
grep -vi session some.log | sed -e '/^$/d' | tail -1
```

When I run this command on a terminal, while connected using SSH to the (self hosted) Github runner instance:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-16-12-250:~$ unbuffer aws ecs execute-command --region eu-west-1 --cluster qa-devops-1-productname --task b75a377a63f44938ae7bacc50c852723 --container ops-machine --command 'sh -c "ls -l /productname ; echo $?"' --interactive > some.log ; grep -vi session some.log | sed -e '/^$/d' | tail -1
0
```

As you can see in the above example, the command outputs successfully the exit status.

So next, I want to insert the output into a variable called "result":

```
ubuntu@ip-10-16-12-250:~$ result=$(unbuffer aws ecs execute-command --region eu-west-1 --cluster qa-devops-1-productname --task b75a377a63f44938ae7bacc50c852723 --container ops-machine --command 'sh -c "ls -l /productname ; echo $?"' --interactive > some.log ; grep -vi session some.log | sed -e '/^$/d' | tail -1)
ubuntu@ip-10-16-12-250:~$ echo $result
0
```

But when I place it within a script and run it with the debug attribute (`bash -x`), look at the content of $result:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-16-12-250:~$ ./1.sh
++ unbuffer aws ecs execute-command --region eu-west-1 --cluster qa-devops-1-productname --task b75a377a63f44938ae7bacc50c852723 --container ops-machine --command 'sh -c "ls -l /productname ; echo $?"' --interactive
++ tail -1
++ sed -e '/^$/d'
++ grep -vi session some.log
+ result=$'0\r'
 -ne 0 ]]
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
+ echo 'equals 0'
equals 0
```

For some reason result variable contains "$'0\r'" instead of just 0.

Also tried this:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-16-12-250:~$ ./1.sh
++ unbuffer aws ecs execute-command --region eu-west-1 --cluster qa-devops-1-productname --task b75a377a63f44938ae7bacc50c852723 --container ops-machine --command 'sh -c "ls -l /productname ; echo $?"' --interactive
++ tail -1
++ sed -e '/^$/d'
++ grep -vi session some.log
+ result=$'0\r'
++ grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}'
++ echo $'0\r'
 -ne 0 ]]
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
+ echo 'equals 0'
equals 0
```

What could be the reason for that? and how can I make sure result contains only the correct number and nothing else?

Comment: Either `execute-command` or the command being executed is outputting text with DOS line endings, which need to be removed. My guess is that `session.log` is the file using DOS line endings.

Comment: You're right! cat -A some.log shows it indeed, shall I used dos2unix command or something equivalent to remove these chars?

Comment: Exactly. The command substitution removes trailing linefeeds from the output of a command, but does not consider the CR in the CRLF pair as special.

Comment: I suggest using `sed 's/\r//g'` instead of `dos2unix` which is not POSIX

Comment: There are countless duplicates on Stack Overflow for using `dos2unix` to remove DOS line endings from a file before processing it with POSIX tools.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `result` as an integer, and let bash do the work for you:

```
> declare -i result
> result=$(unbuffer aws ecs execute-command --region eu-west-1 
             --cluster qa-devops-1-productname --task b75a377a63f44938ae7bacc50c852723
             --container ops-machine --command 'sh -c "ls -l /productname ; echo $?"'
             --interactive > some.log;
           grep -vi session some.log | sed -e '/^$/d' | tail -1)
> [ ${result -eq 0 ] && echo "Success" || echo "Failure"
```

Comment: [This issue posted with SSM coves this as well.](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/354)